# Is it possible to buid carts with Large Stockpiles or only with Small Stockpiles?

Tags: medieval-engineers

I'd like to build Carts using Large Stockpiles for Wood, Lumber and Stone.
But they broke when I tried.

Is it possible to build Carts only using Small Stockpiles for Wood, Lumber, and Stone?

Comment: A developer replied on this steam post but I can't make sense of it https://steamcommunity.com/app/333950/discussions/0/1471966894874462431/

Comment: @TimmyJim Really there is not enough information there, just a hint.